# more than a hint of beauty

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Her expression is demure, but there’s ***more than a hint of beauty***.

What is it intended to convey? Is she beautiful, or not so beautiful?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: She's ***fairly, quite*** beautiful. [macmillandictionary.com](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hint_1): **more than a hint of something (=a lot of something):** *The profession welcomed the recommendations with **more than a hint of relief**.* It's nearly always used as a form of "deliberate understatement".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, but what does the example mean?

Comment: It means what I said. She's fairly beautiful. But beauty is in the eye of the beholder, so one mans "somewhat" beautiful could be another man's ***stunningly*** beautiful. All we can be sure of is she's definitely not "plain" or "ugly" in the writer's opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it’s very kind of you to give such a detailed comment. But I’m sorry that I didn’t mean benny’s example, I actually meant your example which I didn’t quiet understand.

Comment: Have a look at [What is the difference between “some” and “little”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/), and note particularly that ***understatement*** is very common in English. So if I say I can speak a little French, for example, you should probably assume I can hold a conversation in French perfectly well, not that I just know how to order a couple of beers in a bar.

Answer (score 1):

It is stating the subject is beautiful. The look on her face is shy or reserved, but her features are attractive.